# Communication about deletion

Tags: discussion

Why isn't there a communication of cause when an answer is deleted?  I signed up a few days ago and posted my second answer to someone and was maliciously downvoted then deleted but someone with a huge reputation.

Nothing like "Such and Such is unacceptable" to give a clue as to any mistake.  As it is not it just feels like the Reputed Music Professor was simply guarding his territory as resident know-it-all. Not saying that's true, just what it feels like.

Is this just a communication flaw inherent for stack exchange?

The post presently retains 2 downvotes and a single user claimed responsibility for both, which doesn't seem fair as a criteria for deletion, without mentioning the absurdity of the "reason". Keep in mind he or she only gave reason after I solicited the downvoter to communicate. A message which actually earned at least one upvote on the answer.  I feel that if more people had a say in this it would be undeleted.

[Tonality and Rules](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/43095/tonality-and-rules/117808#117808)

Answer (score 4):

I am the user who claimed responsibility for both downvotes. I hardly have a "*huge reputation;*" I used to be fairly active on the site, but after being completely inactive for quite some time, I have recently been barely active.

As I indicated in my comment, but did not make as clear as I could have, I downvoted your answer because I thought that it was not a productive answer. Then I noticed that the answer was peddling a book published by you and sold on your website, so I flagged the answer as spam. The system *automatically* places a downvote on answers that are flagged as spam. That is why I claimed the two downvotes in my comment to you. There was already one downvote on the answer when I found it.

As for my not leaving a comment in the first place, note that SO in general does not require comments to accompany downvotes; it isn't even really encouraged. When you requested clarification in an edit to your question, I could see how getting two downvotes in short order could be frustrating, so I left a comment.

Comment: Well, I don't mean to disparage anyone with a huge reputation. There is nothing wrong with having one. If you would allow me I would send you a copy of the book completely free. The difficulty I am having is that the book is rare and therefore most people are unfamiliar with it. Imagine if I gave the same answer and simply said, yeah this is what I learned in High School Music class.  No? Affiliation is with schooling in that situation. Its not like I created the system myself.  Just something you overlooked.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, Chisao, you caught me right as I was leaving a comment to you on [your other answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/117792/21766). (The comment was posted after your first answer was deleted and shortly before you posted this question.)

In short, if you promote a product that you are connected to in some way, here at Stack Exchange [you *must* disclose that affiliation](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). Since this affiliation was not disclosed, it was originally marked as spam and brought to our attention. Furthermore, I felt that the answer didn't really ever address the original question: of how one can create a sense of tonal orientation around a single pitch. Without an appropriate answer to that question, I unfortunately felt compelled to delete it.

The corollary to this, of course, is that we ask you to edit your other answer to disclose your affiliation with the product.

Comment: I have edited the comment to remove all things considered promotion and included quotes to show where relevant to the original question.  If you wish to consider removing the flag as spam and deletion.